# Big O complexities of my Huffman Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Can someone please tell me the Space and time Complexities, in Bog O notation, of this Huffman code with a little explanation. Would be very much appreciated, thanks. And please do mention the Big O of each method separately, would be great. Thanks.

```
package HuffmanProject;

import java.util.*;

class MyHCode {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String test = "My name is Zaryab Ali";
int[] FreqArray = new int[256];

for (char c : test.toCharArray()) {
FreqArray[c]++;
        }
MyHTree tree = ImplementTree(FreqArray);

System.out.println("CHARACTER\tFREQUENCY\tBINARY EQUIVALEENT CODE");
PrintMyHCode(tree, new StringBuffer());
    }

public static MyHTree ImplementTree(int[] FreqArray) {
PriorityQueue<MyHTree> trees = new PriorityQueue<MyHTree>();

for (int i = 0; i < FreqArray.length; i++) {
if (FreqArray[i] > 0) {
trees.offer(new MyHLeaf(FreqArray[i], (char) i));
            }
        }
while (trees.size() > 1) {
MyHTree FChild = trees.poll();
MyHTree SChild = trees.poll();
trees.offer(new MyHNode(FChild, SChild));
        }
return trees.poll();
    }

public static void PrintMyHCode(MyHTree tree, StringBuffer prefix) {

if (tree instanceof MyHLeaf) {
MyHLeaf leaf = (MyHLeaf) tree;
System.out.println(leaf.CharValue + "\t\t" + leaf.frequency + "\t\t" + prefix);
} 
else if (tree instanceof MyHNode) {
            MyHNode node = (MyHNode) tree;

            prefix.append('0');
            PrintMyHCode(node.left, prefix);
            prefix.deleteCharAt(prefix.length() - 1);

            prefix.append('1');
            PrintMyHCode(node.right, prefix);
            prefix.deleteCharAt(prefix.length() - 1);
        }
    }


}
abstract class MyHTree implements Comparable<MyHTree> {
public int frequency;

public MyHTree(int f) {
        frequency = f;
    }

public int compareTo(MyHTree tree) {
        return frequency - tree.frequency;
    }
}

class MyHLeaf extends MyHTree {
public char CharValue;

public MyHLeaf(int f, char v) {
        super(f);
        CharValue = v;
    }
}

class MyHNode extends MyHTree {
public MyHTree left, right;

public MyHNode(MyHTree l, MyHTree r) {
        super(l.frequency + r.frequency);
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I'm afraid. But maybe you have a programming problem or question ? Does that code work ?

Comment: You didn't even make the effort to format your code correctly...

Comment: Well, apologies but I was in a hurry. Pavan Kumar answered my question perfectly so thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PrintMyHCode() method iterates through the left & right subtrees until the leaft node is found. If there are n elements in the tree then the complexity of this method would be O(n).

The ImplementTree() method adds values in array to the tree and then it polls on their childs. 
If there are n elements in the array:
    1. The complexity of the for loop in this method will be O(n) as each elements is added to the tree directly
    2. The complexity of while loop in this method will be O(logn) assuming that every node has atleast two children for it.

Hence, the total time complexity for ImplementTree() method in Big O notation would be O(nlogn).

Hope, this answer works for you.